# Catching button press in CustomDialog

Tags: flutter, button, dart, customdialog

I am new to flutter and I'd like to catch the event of the pression of a button in a CustomDialog I have implemented in order to trigger a specific action.

My code:

```
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
          title: title,
          description: description,
          buttonText: "Start",
          myHomePageState: this
      ),
    );
```

I would like to trigger a function when the user click on the button "*Start*" but I don't understand where I can set the `onPressed:` property as I did with the `FloatingActionButton` as example.

Comment: Add your CustomDialog class Code

Answer (score 0):

To give it a button-like functionality, wrap it with a `GestureDetector()`, this detects any actions made by the user on it's child. When wrapped with a `GestureDetetor`, you can then give a function to the `onTap` method, which functions similar to a button's `onPressed`

Here is a link to the Flutter documentation for this:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html